# Twilio MVC project is receiving call, but it never gets to the javascript client

Tags: javascript, c#, twilio

I'm trying to do a proof-of-concept with the `Twilio` service. I downloaded the example `C#` project from `GitHub`, which can be found here: https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/client-quickstart-csharp

With that solution, I'm able to do outbound calls [to my personal mobile phone], and talk back-and-forth.

Now I'm trying to test incoming calls, which is not working.

In the example project, the /voice endpoint is used for both incoming and outgoing calls. When I call from my personal cell phone to my `Twilio` phone, the /voice endpoint is getting hit correctly. But no matter what I do, the call is disconnected. Also, the Twilio.Device.incoming() `function` in the `javascript` client never gets fired.

How can I take the incoming call received at my /voice endpoint, and forward it to my `javascript` client that is running so I'm able to talk back-and-forth with the calling phone?

Here's the VoiceController, with some slight modifications by my:

```
public class VoiceController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string to)
    {
        var callerId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioCallerId"];

        var response = new VoiceResponse();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(to) && !to.Contains("7898"))
        {
            var dial = new Dial(callerId: callerId);

            // wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
            // by checking if the number given has only digits and format symbols
            if (Regex.IsMatch(to, "^[\\d\\+\\-\\(\\) ]+$"))
            {
                dial.Number(to);
            }
            else
            {
                dial.Client(to);
            }

            response.Dial(dial);
        }
        else
        {
            var dial = new Dial(callerId: callerId);
            dial.Number("+15555557898");

            response
                .Say("Transferring your call to the Twilio client, Jose.")
                .Dial(dial);
        }

        return Content(response.ToString(), "text/xml");
    }
}
```

And here's the `javascript` code (directly from the quickstart.js that is provided in the project; I removed alot of the other functions that are irrelevant to this question):

```
$(function () {

  $.getJSON('/token')
    .done(function (data) {

      // Setup Twilio.Device
      Twilio.Device.setup(data.token);

      Twilio.Device.ready(function (device) {
        log('Twilio.Device Ready!');
        document.getElementById('call-controls').style.display = 'block';
      });

///////
// ERROR/PROBLEM HERE
///////
// It never hits this function
      Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
        log('Incoming connection from ' + conn.parameters.From);
        var archEnemyPhoneNumber = '+12099517118';

        if (conn.parameters.From === archEnemyPhoneNumber) {
          conn.reject();
          log('It\'s your nemesis. Rejected call.');
        } else {
          // accept the incoming connection and start two-way audio
          conn.accept();
        }
      });
    })
    .fail(function () {
      log('Could not get a token from server!');
    });   
});
```

**Edit: In response to @ADyson comments/questions...**

"Does .done() callback fire": Yes, when running the example app, the Home/Index page loads. The $.getJSON(/token) is called hitting the TokenController in the MVC code. It gets a valid token, and returns the relevant JSON, here's the TokenController:

```
public class TokenController : Controller
{
    // GET: /token
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Load Twilio configuration from Web.config
        var accountSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAccountSid"];
        var authToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAuthToken"];
        var appSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioTwimlAppSid"];

        // Create a random identity for the client
        var identity = "Jose";

        // Create an Access Token generator
        var scopes = new HashSet<IScope>
        {
            { new IncomingClientScope(identity) },
            { new OutgoingClientScope(appSid) }
        };

        var capability = new ClientCapability(accountSid, authToken, scopes: scopes);
        var token = capability.ToJwt();

        return Json(new
        {
            identity,
            token
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Then, the .done() callback receives the JSON, logs the valid token, then executes the "Twilio.Device.setup(data.token)" call to validate with Twilio. Once that is done, it calls the Twilio.Device.ready() function, which then logs "Twilio.Device Ready!".

The app is then ready for phone calls at this point. There are no errors or warning in this process, everything works perfect.

"What is the relevance of the Index() method on the controller": The Index method on the Voice controller is used for both the incoming and outgoing phone calls. When running the example app, there's a phone number text box where you can enter the phone number, then click "Call". Clicking that will execute this javascript:

```
  // Bind button to make call
  document.getElementById('button-call').onclick = function () {
    // get the phone number to connect the call to
    var params = {
      To: document.getElementById('phone-number').value
    };

    console.log('Calling ' + params.To + '...');
    Twilio.Device.connect(params);
  };
```

The "Twilio.Device.connect()" calls Twilio's system, gets the webhook url to make the call, which is "https://{myngrokurl}.ngrok.io/voice". That's how it hits my Voice/Index endpoint, which then makes the call. All of this works perfect (outgoing calls).

Now, for the incoming calls, those are also routed to the Voice/Index endpoint, as configured in the Twilio Admin interface (there's only 1 endpoint for both incoming and outgoing calls). In that code, which you can see above, when the incoming call gets here, it ends up doing a "response.Dial()". This is where I'm assuming it's supposed to route the call to the client javascript; specifically, it should be hitting this javascript code:

```
  Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
    log('Incoming connection from ' + conn.parameters.From);
    var archEnemyPhoneNumber = '+12099517118';

    if (conn.parameters.From === archEnemyPhoneNumber) {
      conn.reject();
      log('It\'s your nemesis. Rejected call.');
    } else {
      // accept the incoming connection and start two-way audio
      conn.accept();
    }
  });
```

But that's the part that is not working. The incoming call successfully hits the Voice/Index endpoint, but it never hits the javascript Twilio.Device.incoming function.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Are we to understand that the ".done()" callback fires, and that all the Twilio handlers are executed correctly to attach the "ready" and "incoming" callbacks? Are there any errors or warnings in your Javascript console at any point during the whole process?

Comment: Also, what's the relevance of the "Index()" controller method? When does that get executed? The JS you've shown calls an endpoint called "Token()" which you haven't shown.

Comment: @ADyson question has been updated to try and address your comments/questions

Comment: Thankyou. "This is where I'm assuming it's supposed to route the call to the client javascript;". Sort of. I believe it'll send an XML response back to the caller something like the example here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial . I assume this then means twilio will try to dial your number. Did you do all the setup to tie your development environment to the Twilio server, set up a capability token etc? https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/quickstart . I'm not a twilio expert btw, it's just my observation from the docs. Your code looks basically ok, I think...

Comment: See also the docs for "incoming" at https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/device I'm guessing you may have read all this already, but just so you know what I'm basing my comment on.

Comment: For your first (of the 2nd set) of comments/questions, yes, the xml is getting returned via the response.Dial(). I would have assumed that the capability token, etc stuff is/was configured correctly since I can successfully do outbound calls, but I'll go back and check again to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've made some progress. I'm now able to receive calls, but not how I want to.

I made a change to check to see if the incoming call (the "to") parameter was equal to MY [Twilio] phone number. If it is, then instead of dialing that phone number, I had it dial my "client", "Jose". When doing that, I'm now able to receive the phone call and talk to the caller.

So, is that how all of this stuff is supposed to work? If the incoming call is supposed to go to "me", then change it from the phone number and go to my "identity"?

I'll keep playing around with it...

Here's the modified version of the code that is working so far:

```
public class VoiceController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string to)
    {
        var callerId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioCallerId"];

        var response = new VoiceResponse();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(to))
        {
            var dial = new Dial(callerId: callerId);

            // wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
            // by checking if the number given has only digits and format symbols
            if (to.Contains(myPhoneNumber))
            {
                dial.Client("Jose"); // this works!
            }
            else if (Regex.IsMatch(to, "^[\\d\\+\\-\\(\\) ]+$"))
            {
                dial.Number(to);
            }
            else
            {
                dial.Client(to);
            }

            response.Dial(dial);
        }
        else
        {
            var dial = new Dial(callerId: callerId);
            dial.Number("+15555557898");

            response
                .Say("Transferring your call to the Twilio client, Jose.")
                .Dial(dial);
        }

        return Content(response.ToString(), "text/xml");
    }
}
```